# Exportar resultado de uma busca para .Txt

Tags: mysql

Uso o MySQL Workbench.
Gostaria de saber como posso Salvar o resultado de uma consulta em um arquivo txt. e que fique separado por tabulação, já tentei de tudo mais nada da certo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só clicar no botão '*Export recordset to an external file*':

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]